# Infinite loop in Camel : message broker to soap

Tags: java, spring, soap, apache-camel, rabbitmq

i have defined route in the apache camel which reads queue and then send request to the soap web service and which is then passed to response queue on rabbit mq, problem is that this route becomes infinite route from the rabbitmq queue to soap web service even though it just contains one message. 
following is the code ,

```
<route >
            <from uri="rabbitmq://localhost/exchangename?username=user&amp;password=password;autoDelete=false&amp;routingKey=key;queue=nameofqueue" />
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
            <to uri="cxf:bean:helloWorldEndpoint?defaultOperationName=sayHelloWorld" />
            <to uri="rabbitmq://localhost/response exchange?username=name&amp;password=passwd&amp;routingKey=responsekey&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;queue=nameofresponsequeue" />
</route>
```

What  I am doing wrong ?

Edit: So I tried chanding last "to" to the "file" component , it works fine without any problem .So it has comething to do with RabbitMq. Also before this route I have another route as following :

```
<route id="differentRoute">
            <from uri="file:C:\\file" />            
            <to uri="rabbitmq://localhost/exchangename?username=user&amp;password=password;autoDelete=false&amp;routingKey=key;queue=nameofqueue" />
</route>
```

so I am reading from file, sending to request queue in first route and then in second route reading from the request queue, sending soap request and then putting response in the response queue.

Answer (score 0):

can you add the parameter

```
dataFormat=MESSAGE on the cxf endpoint
```

Since you are sending a plain xml , the dataformat needs to be message , if you are sending POJO can you please post the stacktrace.

Comment: this has nothing to do with cxf endpoint because if i change last "to"  file, it works fine without any problem.